# How to know if my tablet is compatible to a later Android version?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, 2.2-froyo

I have a Pandigital Star tablet with Android 2.2.

But now Pandigital have closed their business. 
I would like to Upgrade to atleast Android 2.3 myself.

1. Can I do it?
2. Should I do it? Will it make my system slow?
3. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Can you do it ? Yes you can, how hard or time consuming is it going to be? A lot of time for sure.
2. Sure you can go ahead! Many people run custom roms or build their own roms from AOSP on their android devices.
3. You can either search for compatiable custom roms for your device else go pull a branch of AOSP and build on it!

Comment: Please answer in details. Where to get custom roms etc.

Comment: [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575)

Comment: I actually did a little searching for you, just a little, couldn't find anything solid! Looks like you will have to do some deep searching on your own. The comment by @Izzy seems to have the sources you should look at.

PS: I think this answers your question